# How to create new dataframe by filtering a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few datasets that share the same columns so I concatenated them together to form one large dateframe. My idea is to filter a goals_per_90 column by > .5 so it will create a new dataframe showing those whole rows of all the players with a value greater than .5 in a new dataframe. Im thinking of something like this at the moment but getting stuck when

```
 def gettopplayers(Dataframe):
   if Dataframe.loc[Dataframe['goals_per_90_overall'] > .5]:
     apply.
```

Im getting lost as to where to append this row to.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Adding minimal example with expected output may be helpful for others to answer.

Comment: If you are trying to create a new DataFrame by filtering rows of another Dataframe returning the `df.loc[condition]` will do the job

Answer (score 2):

Below python code will make a new dataframe with all the rows where the condition is met. No need for the `if` condition.

```
df_new = Dataframe.loc[(Dataframe['goals_per_90_overall'] > .5)]
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what loc is doing here: [(Dataframe['goals_per_90_overall'] > .5)]? I am struggling to understand how to use loc but, I see it so much with pandas.

Comment: @TechNewbie The `Dataframe['goals_per_90_overall'] > .5` produces a tuple of boolean values meeting the following condition. `DF.loc()` takes the tuple as input and returns the entire rows with corresponding index. `loc` is usually label based but can be used with booleans as in the above example. The best source for Pandas learning is the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html